# pip install numpy and scipy on windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip

I have installed python to create a deep neural network on Windows 10 to 64-bit. I installed the version 3.5 and after the version 2.7. In any case, I could not install numpy and SciPy with the pip command. In fact, I will open the command prompt as administrator, launch the command "pip install numpy" and it print:

```
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\claud\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-93rn_o\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\claud\appdata\local\temp\pip-lw65ht-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\claud\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-93rn_o\numpy
```

I also downloaded the installer of [numpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.10.1/) and [scipy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.16.0/), but nothing yet. I also tried to install Anaconda, but I can not find any way to install numpy and scipy. What should I do?

Comment: Please check that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31998000/524743

Comment: @ClaudioGuerriero Please remove the question if you found the solution elsewhere

Comment: you could check out anaconda python, it is very handy and provides a package manager.

Comment: @ClaudioGuerriero You should use Anaconda for installing packages from  SciPy stack (IPython, NumPy, Matplotlib, ...)